# training loss is Nan - but trainning data is all in range without null

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

When I execute my `model.fit(x_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs=3, shuffle=False, verbose=2)`

I always get loss as nan:

```
Epoch 1/3
73/73 - 5s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5417 - 5s/epoch - 73ms/step
Epoch 2/3
73/73 - 5s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5417 - 5s/epoch - 74ms/step
Epoch 3/3
73/73 - 5s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5417 - 5s/epoch - 73ms/step
```

My x_training is shaped (2475, 48), y_train is shaped (2475,)

- I derive my input train set in (2315, 160, 48), so 2315 sets of training data, 160 as my loopback timewindow, 48 features
- corresspondingly, the y_train is 0 or 1 in shape of (2315, 1)

All in range of (-1,1):
[image: Overview of training data]

My model is like this:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_6 (LSTM)               (None, 160, 128)          90624     
                                                                 
 dropout_4 (Dropout)         (None, 160, 128)          0         
                                                                 
 lstm_7 (LSTM)               (None, 160, 64)           49408     
                                                                 
 dropout_5 (Dropout)         (None, 160, 64)           0         
                                                                 
 lstm_8 (LSTM)               (None, 32)                12416     
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 33        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 152,481
Trainable params: 152,481
Non-trainable params: 0
```

- I tried different LSTM units: 48, 60, 128, 160, none of them work
- I check my training data, all of them are in the range of (-1,1)
- There is no 'null' in my dataset, `x_train.isnull().values.any()` outputs False

Now I have no clue where can I try more~

My model code is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

def create_model(win = 100, features = 9):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation='relu', input_shape=(win, features),
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(LSTM(units=64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # no need return sequences from 'the last layer'
    model.add(LSTM(units=32))

    # adding the output layer
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # may also try mean_squared_error
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

here I plot some train_y samples:
[image: y_train is 0 or 1 labels]

Comment: How do you compile your model? Loss function, last layer output/activation - checked? Is it possible to share reproducible stuff?

Comment: @M.Innat I just uploaded code of my model for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

2022.Mar.17 update

After further debugging, I eventually found out the problem is actually because of my newly added feature contains `np.inf`, after I remove those rows, my problem resolved, I can see the loss value now

```
6/6 [==============================] - 2s 50ms/step - loss: 0.6936 - accuracy: 0.5176
```

Note, np.inf has symbol, so make sure both `np.inf` and `-np.inf` are removed:

```
all_dataset = all_dataset[all_dataset.feature_issue != np.inf]
all_dataset = all_dataset[all_dataset.feature_issue != -np.inf]
```

---

2022.Mar.16

After some debugging, I addressed 2 of my new added features actually cause the problem. So, the problem comes from data, but unlike the others, my data contains no nan, no out of range(originally I thought all the data needs to be normalized)

But I can't tell the reason yet, as they looks good

I will continue research more on it tomorrow, any advice is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two things: try normalizing your time series data and using `relu` as the activation function for `lstm` layers is not 'conventional'. Check this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444923/activation-function-between-lstm-layers) for further insights. An example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
import tensorflow as tf

layer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
x = tf.random.normal((500, 100, 9))
y = tf.random.uniform((500, ), dtype=tf.int32, maxval=2)
layer.adapt(x)

def create_model(win = 100, features = 9):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layer)
    model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation='tanh', input_shape=(win, features),
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(LSTM(units=64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(units=32))

    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = create_model()

model.fit(x, y, epochs=20)
```

Comment: I just tried tanh, relu, sigmoid, no activation, does not work! BTW, my dataset is normalized as I mentioned in my description.

Comment: Can you show the `model.fit` part?

Comment: model.fit(x_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs=3, batch_size=64, shuffle=False, verbose=1)

Comment: and a sample of x_train_lstm? and y_train_lstm?

Comment: y_train_lstm is just 0 or 1 as my labels, x_train_lstm is in shape  (2315, 160, 48), in range (-1, 1), there is a plotting of x_train in my description

Comment: a x_train sample is like:    array([[-0.090212  , -0.04325221,  0.01507063, ...,  0.1007919 ,
         0.13871902,  0.10845089],
       [-0.11270548, -0.08728496, -0.02739808, ...,  0.10102842,
         0.13952859,  0.11148659],
       [-0.0815856 , -0.08153108, -0.02805241, ...,  0.10170061,
         0.13986657,  0.11421693],
       ...,

Comment: Yes I am sure, I ploted y_train, see my updated description

Comment: Ok, I am asking because your model itself is fine. Meaning it must be something with your data.

Comment: I had a simple version was working, in this version my change was moving from 9 features to 48 from my dataset, not sure if I missed anything parameter

Comment: Hey, please checkout my updated answer, it is because of np.inf